# Missing EdiMessageContent Table

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I've got a new BizTalk group I've just created (with BizTalk Server 2006 R2 SP1).  When I go to run the DTA purge job it complains with "Invalid object name 'EdiMessageContent'".  This table does not exist in the DTA database.

So I compared my setup with another group I have where the purge job does work.  Sure enough that one has the table.  So the two groups differ by just this one table.

Strange.  How come this table didn't get created?  Is that because I'm running SP1?  I do see a script in the schema folder named BtsEdiMessageContentTables.sql and I was able to run it successfully on a blank database.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Krip

Comment: I see Ricardo has the same problem:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vi-VN/biztalkgeneral/thread/8125bef7-a459-4d63-bf50-6ac5d71e8efa

Answer (score 0):

I'll take my own stab at this: It's a problem with SP1.  So I've just run the sql script I found that creates and indexes the new table, and now the purge job runs fine.  That table didn't have any rows in my other environment anyway since I don't use EDI.  So I think I'm good to go.

Anyone else faced this or worked around it?

-Krip